# Installing pyephem or astropy on Pyzo

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pyephem, astropy

For some months I learn programming with python. I use Pyzo with its IEP (Interactive Editor for Python) on my Windows 7 computer. Pyzo is available from www.pyzo.org/index.html.

In Pyzo, it is very easy to execute python-code or just several lines of code. Another advantage of Pyzo is, that it is user-friendly and easy to use. Furthermore, some packages like numpy, scipy or matplotlib are preinstalled.

My specifications are

- IEP version: 3.3.dev (source)
- Platform: win32
- Python version: 3.3.2
- Qt version: 4.8.4
- PySide version: 1.2.1

Recently I developed the wish to install new packages into Pyzo. To be able to do this I had to put Pyzo to the registry. Hence I executed the command

```
pyzo_activate
```

in the windows command prompt. Afterwards I was able to install a package called scitools. Then I intended to install the package pyephem from http ://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/. 
I downloaded the windows installer file ephem-3.7.5.3.win32-py3.3.exe from the site https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ephem/. Now, if I start the installation process by executing the installer, the installer does not find python3.3 in the registry.
Does anyone know remedy? How can I install pyephem into Pyzo?

I have the same problem, if I try to install the package astropy via the windows installer astropy-0.4.2.win32-py3.3.exe from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astropy/0.4.2. In this case, python3.3 isn't recognized, too.

It would be very kind, if somebody could give me help. Otherwise I encourage the developers of pyephem and astropy to make future versions able to be installed into Pyzo.

Comment: Did you try a `pip install ephem` or `pip install astropy`? I think that the installers you downloaded from PyPI are designed for use with the official version of Python from the Python web site — so, when they look around at the registry entries, they are confused because none of the registry keys for that official version of Python are available, so they do not know where to install.

Comment: Are you sure that `pip install ephem` also works on windows operating systems? Where do I have to execute this command, from `C:\pyzo2013c` or from `C:\Users\Christoph` or from somewhere else? And which files do I have to download before executing this command? And where do I have to place the downloaded files?

Answer (score 2):

According to Pyzo's [website](http://www.pyzo.org/index.html), Pyzo uses [Conda](http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda) for package installations. You should be able to do the following:

```
conda install ephem
conda install astropy
```

You should not expect unpaid developers to port their code to every permutation of Python environments out there. These alternate Python environments should include a way to install packages. Fortunately in this case, conda was there to assist with this.

Comment: Here, I have the same question: Where do I have to execute this command, from C:\pyzo2013c or from C:\Users\Christoph or from somewhere else? And which files do I have to download before executing this command? And where do I have to place the downloaded files?

Comment: I am aware of the developers being very busy. I just wanted to mention the issue. I know that I mustn't demand that everything is compatible with everything.

Comment: I've never installed Pyzo, but I could just try typing that command in a terminal and see if it works. If it does not, then you'll need to find where `conda` is located on your system, which is probably in `C:\pyzo2013c` somewhere. Then you can do something like `C:\pyzo2013c\some_folder\conda install ephem`

Comment: If just typing `conda` does not work then you should use the search tool of your operating system (I think it is beneath the “Start” menu somewhere on Windows, over in the lower left?) to look for files named `conda` and it should come up.